# Mac VPN connection not network available

Tags: macbook-pro

I used to connect to my job's VPN using IPSec smoothly for a while. After rebooting the laptop yesterday I now can't connect to the VPN and I get this error:[image]

I'm not exactly what I'm doing wrong here. I have reconfigured the VPN many times and my internet connection works fine on the laptop yet I still get this error. I can connect to the VPN using my deskptop just fine.

Any suggestions on what I may be missing?

Comment: I'd help future readers if you accept your own answer. Then the entire question counts as answered.

Answer (score 0):

A little more searching on the internet gave me the solution.

"...What I did is open Keychain Access and grant the VPN certificate (the private key part) to allow for all applications to access..." by msltx.

I wish the error was a little more specific to guide users to the right fix.

[Answer Reference](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4139538?tstart=0)

**EDIT:**

To specify what I did I opened the application "Keychain Access", found the certificate that my job's VPN is using, right click, evaluate and allow. Then it all worked.

[image]

Comment: How include more information on what you did exactly?  I see somebody from that linked discussions somebody already did that.  It would be useful to have that information here at Superuser.